# Web server controls to handle relationships/juntion table insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, many-to-many, insert-update

I'm having trouble with an asp.net c# insert/edit form.

Say you have a table for Employees.  Now each Employee could have one or many Categories assigned to them. Each Category has Subcategories and the user can be assigned to one or more subcategories for each of the categories.

Table Structure:

```
EmployeeTable
id
Fname
Lname
City

CategoryTable
id
CategoryName

SubCategoryTable
id
SubCategoryName

JuntionTable
EmployeeTable_id
CategoryTable_id
SubCategoryTable_id
```

The insert/edit web form is where I'm struggling.  EmployeeTable date will be text boxes, and since a Employee can be in more than one Category, and within that Category each can have multiple SubCategories, how do you set up your server controls to handle this?  Can a treeview control handle this with parent/child/nodes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to stick to the built-in controls for executing insert operations then you will need to do the bulk of the logic in your SQL statement for inserting.

You can do this in any TreeView, FormView, or most any other similar container. You'll need to wire each control up to the parameter it should be sending to, and maybe write some logic to populate nested controls based on other selected values. Depending on how you are structuring the database you may also need to use nested Views, each with their own insert logic.

If each table already has it's own SQL Stored Procedures created then I would probably use nested View controls.